# ms:script tags in XSLT

Tags: javascript, .net, xslt

I am attempting to migrate an ASP Classic application to .Net 4.0 (4.5 would also be acceptable). The application is responsible for performing XSL Transformations using Javascript extension functions.  The ASP Classic application currently uses MSXML 4.0 to perform the transformations.

I am running into problems in .Net when I try and use the XslCompiledTransform class to process a transform that includes javascript extensions. It works for simple examples but we have a fairly extensive javascript library and I am seeing error as the test cases become increasingly complex.  The most frustrating of these errors are syntax errors, for example the .Net parser doesn't seem to like statements outside of functions.

Can anyone tell me which class is used to parse and compile the javascript extensions and if there is thorough documentation anywhere.  Also can the the javascript processor object be replaced with a custom object (in a similar manner to a UriResolver).

Also, is it possible to use the parser rules to have Visual Studio highlight javascript syntax errors when viewing the file. I am pretty sure it already does this for javascript code that is used in web pages and such, but the syntax rules seem to be different in XSLT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIR XslCompiledTransform uses CodeDom to compile embedded scripts. The way it works is that XslCompiledTransform creates a code file that is then passed to CodeDom for compilation. I believe MSXML uses a different JavaScript engine than the one used by CodeDom. Hence the compilation problem. In addition (it's been a while since I looked at it) there may be some additional processing happening to make the scripts compilable (I remember that for scripts in C# there was a class created and all functions were put to this class). 
Note that the assemblies created by CodeDom are loaded to the appdomain where the transformation is executed. This may lead to OutOfMemory exceptions since the CLR does not allow to unload assemblies - I wrote about this some time ago here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2011/09/26/effective-xml-part-5-something-went-really-wrong-outofmemoryexception-and-stackoverflowexception-thrown-when-using-xslcompiledtransform.aspx